# Rails: Change next_page class of will_paginate gem

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, will-paginate

Is possible to change the class name 'next_page' of will paginate gem? For example is easy to change .paginate class, but I don't know if is possibile with 'next_page'

```
:class - CSS class name for the generated DIV (default: "pagination")
:previous_label - default: "« Previous"
:next_label - default: "Next »"
:page_links - when false, only previous/next links are rendered (default: true)
:inner_window - how many links are shown around the current page (default: 4)
:outer_window - how many links are around the first and the last page (default: 1)
:link_separator - string separator for page HTML elements (default: single space)
:param_name - parameter name for page number in URLs (default: :page)
:params - additional parameters when generating pagination links (eg.             :controller => "foo", :action => nil)
:renderer - class name, class or instance of a link renderer (default in Rails: WillPaginate::ActionView::LinkRenderer)
:container - toggles rendering of the DIV container for pagination links, set to false only when you are rendering your own pagination markup (default: true)
```

Comment: Why you need to change the class name?

Answer (score 0):

Once you are allowed to change the *enclosing* class name, changing nested class names is redundant and hence not provided.

Use CSS selector `.pagination > .next_page` to avoid any possible name clashes.